# Google Checkout XML invalid value

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, google-checkout, jigoshop

I'm using a plugin called http://www.jigoshop.com with Wordpress (both the latest versions) and I'm having problems with their Google Checkout gateway.

I've tried their support but yet to get a response.

I'm getting the following errors when trying to order something:

> Error parsing XML; message from parser is: Invalid value for attribute
>   unit-price in shopping-cart.items.item-2.unit-price: Required field
>   must not be blank

In the Google merchant console this translates to:

"XML that we recieved"

```
_type=checkout-shopping-cart&shopping-cart.merchant-private-data=273&checkout-flow-support.merchant-checkout-flow-support.continue-shopping-url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.carolinemontagu.com%2Fv2%2Fevents%2Fcheckout%2Fthanks%2F&checkout-flow-support.merchant-checkout-flow-support.edit-cart-url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.carolinemontagu.com%2Fv2%2Fevents%2Forder%2F&shopping-cart.items.item-1.item-name=Leadership+Success%3A+Early+bird+%26%238211%3B+19th+Oct&shopping-cart.items.item-1.item-description=&shopping-cart.items.item-1.unit-price=205.83&shopping-cart.items.item-1.unit-price.currency=GBP&shopping-cart.items.item-1.quantity=1&shopping-cart.items.item-1.merchant-item-id=211&shopping-cart.items.item-2.item-name=Shipping&shopping-cart.items.item-2.item-description=&shopping-cart.items.item-2.unit-price=&shopping-cart.items.item-2.unit-price.currency=GBP&shopping-cart.items.item-2.quantity=1&shopping-cart.items.item-2.merchant-item-id=
```

"XML that we sent"

```
_type=error&error-message=Error+parsing+XML%3B+message+from+parser+is%3A+Invalid+value+for+attribute+unit-price+in+shopping-cart.items.item-2.unit-price%3A+Required+field+must+not+be+blank&serial-number=3f096700-bb6f-4e28-8740-f6ffa0d09aeb
```

I've had a look through their code and can find this that corresponds to `shopping-cart.items.item-2.unit-price`:

```
private function formatOrder(jigoshop_order $order) {
    $result = array(
        '_type' => 'checkout-shopping-cart',
        'shopping-cart.merchant-private-data' => $order->id,
        'checkout-flow-support.merchant-checkout-flow-support.continue-shopping-url' => get_permalink(get_option('jigoshop_thanks_page_id')),
        'checkout-flow-support.merchant-checkout-flow-support.edit-cart-url' => get_permalink(get_option('jigoshop_cart_page_id')),
        //shipping-taxed
    );

    $i = 1;
    foreach($order->items as $item) {
        $prefix = "shopping-cart.items.item-$i.";//shopping-cart.items.item-1.item-name

        $result[$prefix.'item-name'] = $item['name'];
        $result[$prefix.'item-description'] = '';
        $result[$prefix.'unit-price'] = $item['cost'];
        $result[$prefix.'unit-price.currency'] = get_option('jigoshop_currency');
        $result[$prefix.'quantity'] = $item['qty'];
        $result[$prefix.'merchant-item-id'] = $item['id'];

        $i++;
    }

    $prefix = "shopping-cart.items.item-$i.";

    $result[$prefix.'item-name'] = __('Shipping', 'jigoshop');
    $result[$prefix.'item-description'] = '';
    $result[$prefix.'unit-price'] = $order->order_shipping;
    $result[$prefix.'unit-price.currency'] = get_option('jigoshop_currency');
    $result[$prefix.'quantity'] = 1;
    $result[$prefix.'merchant-item-id'] = $order->shipping_method;

    return $result;
}
```

Can anyone help with this problem? I'm really stuck with a deadline looming fast!

Comment: Is there an item in your database that has no 'cost' assigned to it? That's one of the first things I would look at.

Comment: @vascowhite I'll have a look now.

Comment: If you know what item 2 was in that particular cart, that will narrow it down a bit. Unfortunately I have no experience whatsoever with google checkout other than as a customer, so I'm unlikely to be able to help any further.

Comment: @vascowhite I tried deleting all the products from the cms then added a new one and the same message appears. Really frustrating!

Comment: @vascowhite It's strange how the error message references item 2 yet I'm only trying to buy 1 item. It's like it's trying to add another item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you added only one item to the shopping cart, then based on the code provided, item-2 is the shipping cost.

Make sure your $order->order_shipping is initialized correctly.

Comment: Thanks, how would I check that?

Comment: Thanks very much, you got me thinking. As my products don't include shipping I just set it to 0 and it then processed the payment - $result[$prefix.'unit-price'] = 0;